# Question on applying the constraint $x^Tx=1$ in optimization using eigenvalues of quadratic form $x^TAx$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, quadratics, linear-programming

I am reading a linear algebra chapter on constrained optimization.

> Let A be a symmetric matrix and $x^TAx$ the quadratic form of a quadratic function.
> Subject to the constraint $x^Tx=1$, the Max is the largest eigenvalue, $\lambda_{max}$, of A and is attained when x is a unit eigenvector $u_i$ corresponding to $\lambda_{max}$.

I follow the book contents and find this method neat as many functions in engineering and economics are quadratic.
But the book is very light on how to apply the constraint $x^Tx=1$ in practice.
For a constraint having **only** *quadratic terms*, I think we can transform it to $x^Tx=1$ using change of variable like this (right?).
$$\begin{align}
Constraint(x,y) &= 5x^2 + 7y^2 =28 \\
& = \frac{5x^2}{5\cdot7} + \frac{7y^2}{5\cdot7}=\frac{28}{5\cdot7} \\
&= (\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}})^2 + (\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}})^2 = \frac{28}{35}\\
&= \frac{35}{28}\cdot((\frac{x}{\sqrt{7}})^2 + (\frac{y}{\sqrt{5}})^2) = 1\\
&= (\sqrt{\frac{35}{196}}\cdot x)^2 + (\sqrt{\frac{35}{140}}\cdot y)^2 = 1\\
&= x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1 \qquad\text{for } x_1=\sqrt{\frac{35}{196}}\cdot x, x_2=\sqrt{\frac{35}{140}}\cdot y\\
&= x^Tx =1\\
\end{align}$$

My questions are:

1. For any single constraint having **only** quadratic terms, is it always possible like above to use change of variable to make it $x^Tx=1$?
2. What if the constraint has cross-product terms? How can you make it $x^Tx=1$?
3. In practice, an objective function is often subject to multiple constraints. Does this linear algebra method still work or not? If yes, how?
4. Any suggested books/materials where I can learn more, including the above general situations?

Comment: I don't have a background in economics, but in my experience it would be unusual to find a practical optimization problem which can be expressed as maximizing $x^T Ax$ subject to $x^T x= 1$. This fact about eigenvalues is very important and fundamental conceptually, but I think it usually does not lead directly to practical optimization algorithms. So I don't recommend viewing this fact as a tool that's going to directly solve optimization problems. Instead, algorithms from convex optimization such as gradient descent or interior point methods or proximal algorithms tend to be the workhorse.

Comment: so you are saying optimizing $x^TAx$ subject to $x^Tx=1$ is largely an idealized textbook illustration of orthogonalization?

Comment: This fact about eigenvalues is very important theoretically and conceptually. Even if we weren't doing optimization, we would want to know this fact, which is why it's taught in linear algebra courses. I haven't seen your book but maybe they are not trying to illustrate anything at all, they could be just telling you a fundamental thing that you will need to know (even if it does not usually directly solve practical optimization problems).

Comment: @littleO , so this neat method cannot be generalized beyond the textbook? the 2. and 3. above are not doable?

Comment: If you have a problem of the form maximize $x^T A x$ subject to $x^T Bx = 1$, where $B$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, then you could factor $B$ as $B = L^T L$ (using the Cholesky factorization) and make a change of variable $y = Lx$. Then the optimization problem, in terms of $y$, would be to maximize $(L^{-1} y)^T A L^{-1} y = y^T L^{-T} A L^{-1} y$ subject to $y^T y = 1$. But, it's not clear to me how often this turns out to be helpful in practical problems. If it happens to work occasionally, that is a cool thing, but I don't know how common that is.

Comment: @littleO, thanks. I see your point about it being an important concept that goes into other important concepts like singular-value-decomposition etc, but was trying to generalize it for applications in addition to a mere theoretical building block. It seems as you said, it is too far a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Economist here

1. Indeed, you can do it
2. If you have $x'Ax$ and A is symmetric then use the spectral theorem (it also holds for 1.)
3. I'm not sure, by my intuition is that it does not work.
4. This method is very important in economics. Some examples are: factor models, principal components, and Linear-Quadratic approximation of models. In fact, the latter is a very popular way of solving DSGE models

Comment: 2. $A$ is obviously symmetric for $x^TAx$ to hold. By spectral theorem, you refer to orthogonal diagonalization $x^TAx = y^TDy$ where $D = PAP^T$ and $P$ is made of eigenvectors ? That is implicit in the statement above subject to $x^Tx=1$ such that there are no cross-terms in the new variable $y$ but I am asking how to deal with cross-terms of $x$ in the constraint not the objective function.

Comment: Sorry I did not follow. What I understand by no cross terms is that $A$ is not diagonal. I see you have a different definition in mind, could you please explain?

Comment: By spectral theorem I mean that if $A$ is symmetric then $A=UDU'$ so you can define $y=U'x$.

Comment: I call that Principal Axes Theorem, but whatever it's the same thing. The cross-terms in $x$ or equivalently off-diagonals in $A$ of $x^TAx$ is given by the objective function say $f(x) = ax_1^2 + bx_2^2 + cx_1x_2$ in $\mathbf{R^2}$, which if subject to $x^Tx=1$, we can use change of variable $x=Py$ to find max. What I am asking is that when the original constraint function has cross-terms like $20x_1^2 + 18x_2^2 - 12x_1x_2 =40$, is it possible to convert it to $x^Tx = 1$.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure you can do a conversion.

Comment: Most real-world constraints have cross-terms, so I wonder if the constraint can't be made $x^Tx=1$ to begin with, the whole method can't work. Also, most problems have multiple constraints. I am trying to know to what extent this method can be generalized or is it just limited to unrealistic textbook cases where a constraint is readily convertible to $x'x=1$.